# Eclipse cannot resolve composite component attribute of abstract class type

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, abstract-class, composite-component

The code seems to work even though Eclipse is marking the line `#{cc.attrs.bolt.spec.size}` in the bolt_component.xhtml as the property cannot be resolved for `spec.size`

bolt_component.xhtml

```
<composite:attribute name="bolt" type="model.bolts.Bolt" />
#{cc.attrs.bolt.spec.size}
```

my abstract class

```
public abstract class Bolt implements Serializable {
protected BoltSpec spec;
    I have setSpec()
    but not a getSpec()
```

and the concrete class

```
public class BoltHexHead extends Bolt implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private BoltSpecHexHead spec;

public BoltSpecHexHead getSpec() {
    return spec;
}
public void setSpec(BoltSpecHexHead spec) {
    this.spec = spec;
    super.setSpec(spec);
}
```

I realize why Eclipse is flagging because I don't have a getSpec() but when I add getSpec in Bolt  I get a null pointer in my controller which uses the HexHeadBolt `.getSpec()` turns out to be null when it should not be.

```
if (analysisHexHeadWithNutOperational.getBolt().getSpec().getSize() == null) {
```

I've tried multitude of combinations of getters setters private protected, etc...

Is the flagging by Eclipse a bug? Or do I have my inheritance set up incorrectly I'm using Luna

## EDIT

added screenshot showing even with cleaner DRY code, using parameterized property, Eclipses still flags "size" cannot be resolved, but only in the custom component
[image]

## EDIT2

by adding `spec` to cc interface I can get Eclipse to stop flagging

faclet

```
<stk:bolt_component boltTypes="#{data.hexHeadBoltTypes}"
         bolt="#{hex_head_nut_operational.boltAnalysis.bolt}"
         spec="#{hex_head_nut_operational.boltAnalysis.bolt.spec}" />
```

cc

```
composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="boltTypes" /> 
    <composite:attribute name="bolt" />
    <composite:attribute name="spec" />
```

Comment: Have you tried using <composite:attribute name="bolt" /> instead? When the type is Bolt, calling bolt.spec would need an implicit downcast to BoltHexHead which cannot be pickup during compile time as the compiler has no knowledge of which subclass of Bolt to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather you're having trouble figuring out how to use an abstract bolt with a generic abstract bolt spec. In a good abstract class with common properties (and getters/setters) it should not have been necessary to repeat the getter/setter in every subclass and delegate to `super`. The mistake in your `getSpec()` attempt was likely that you didn't delegate to `super`. Moreover, the in subclass repeated `spec` property is unnecessary.

```
public BoltSpecHexHead getSpec() {
    return (BoltSpecHexHead) super.getSpec();
}

public void setSpec(BoltSpecHexHead spec) {
    super.setSpec(spec);
}
```

Actually, this is not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). If the property of the abstract class is in turn also abstract, and you want to avoid casting hell, then you'd better make it a parameterized type.

```
public abstract class BoltSpec {

    // ...

}
```

```
public abstract class Bolt<S extends BoltSpec> {

    private S spec;

    public S getSpec() {
        return spec;
    }

    public void setSpec(S spec) {
        this.spec = spec;
    }

}
```

```
public class BoltSpecHexHead extends BoltSpec {

    // ...

}
```

```
public class BoltHexHead extends Bolt<BoltSpecHexHead> {

    // ... (note: no getSpec()/setSpec() necessary!)

}
```

Comment: Awesome!  You saw through my question to the concrete problem; using an abstract Bolt with an abstract BoltSpec.  However, Eclipse still flags .size which is property of abstract class as "size cannot be resolved" Nonetheless, code still works and fulfills being DRY which is more important.  I've added screenshot for fyi.

Comment: Is `size` defined in `BoltSpec`?

Comment: yes.  @Id private String size; plus getter/setter.  Eclipse does not complain about size in a regular .xhtml faclet page only in the cc.

Comment: Then it's indeed a (nth) false warning by Eclipse.

Comment: If I add spec to the cc interface I can get it to go away.  <stk:bolt_component spec="#{bolt.spec}" ...>  and in cc <composite:attribute name="spec" />.  Is this OK to put a bunch of attributes in interface?

Comment: :) I thought of exactly that, but did find it clutter. If it makes you feel better, just do it. But don't go overboard. E.g. should it be possible to pass technically incompatible bolt and boltspec separately?